# Generating Sample JSON data from JSON Schema

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I have been searching for a java library which can generate sample JSON data looking at and conforming to a given JSON schema. Is anybody aware of any library which can do the job. I haven't been able to get one.

Comment: Don't know about libraries, but there's a possibly-relevant web service here: http://schematic-ipsum.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Yes, I did look at that. But, we need it to be done within our code. I  mostly convinced that there isn't any library available that does what we need. Probably, time to write one.

Comment: actually schematic-ipsum is a library available here
https://github.com/jonahkagan/schematic-ipsum

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can generate the JSON data from sample bean class using the JSON API

```
net.sf.json.JSONObject
```

above library will provide you the method and from below method we can create the jsonobject from the bean class

```
JSONObject.fromObject(yourbean)
```